# H2O: Keep -ice_root when exit?

Tags: r, linux, h2o

Is there a way to keep the directory `ice_root` (eg, `/tmp/RtmpabcDEFGH`) when H2O exits?

- H2O v3.10.5.1
- R v3.3.2
- Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am not running yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are letting h2o.init() start the H2O process, then it starts the H2O process with it's output going to a tempdir().

(Look at the R documentation for tempdir().)

Cleaning up after itself was a requirement for getting accepted by CRAN.

If you want H2O to put its output somewhere else, than start H2O on the command line yourself to get more control.  In the simplest case, this would look like the following:

```
$ java -jar h2o.jar
```

You can find more information about how to start H2O by doing the following:

- http://h2o.ai/download
- Choose latest stable version of H2O
- Follow the instructions in the "Download and Run" tab

Comment: If I start h2o on the command line, will the output in tempdir() remain after exiting/shutdown?

Comment: If you start h2o on the command line the output isn't stored in tempdir() at all.  Yes, it will remain after exiting/shutdown.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.